# RPi Zero with RTC DS1307 - Remote I/O Error

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, real-time-clock

EDIT: This problem is solved! the problem was a script running on the pi, which occupied the SCL pin (in my case a script listening for a shutdown button). So it was not able to read the rtc.

I'm currently following this tutorial to connect my Raspberry Pi Zero W running Jessie Lite to the RTC DS1307. 
The rtc is being recognized when running `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` with "UU", so everything fine until this point. 
But when entering `sudo hwclock -D -r` I'm getting an error:

[image: Error Message]

Does anybody have any experience or hints with this error? I was researching for 1 1/2 day now, but could not find a working solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back then I was not able to answer my own question. I have already edited the main post, but to close this question:

This problem is solved! the problem was a script running on the pi, which occupied the SCL pin (in my case a script listening for a shutdown button). So it was not able to read the rtc.